# Question regarding the Dominant Convergence Theorem for Sequences.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

$\bf{Summary:}$

I don't know if what I have written down is sufficient to understand what I'm trying to ask, so I'll attach an image of the proof for detailed reference at the end.

I'm currently taking an ODE class and going through the proof for the local existence and uniqueness of first order initial value problems. The lecturer uses the dominant convergence theorem to show that a particular sequence uniformly converges. I don't think I have come across this theorem in my Mathematical Analysis I module and when searching online for this theorem I don't understand the formal definition of the proof. The theorem talks about a function of a sequence being integrable and I don't see how it links to the proof (as shown below).

I have not learnt stuff like measure spaces and lesbesgue integrals (I believe these will be covered in Mathematical Analysis II in my university - I will not be taking that course (I'm an applied math student) but am interested to learn them in my free time) So my question is, is there an intuitive definition of DCT? From what my lecturer has written, can I say that:

Consider a sequence $\{x_n(t)\}$, if $ x_n(t) = \sum\text{(of some expression)} $ and that this $\sum\text{(of some expression)} $ is finite, and $ |x_{k+1}(t) - x_{k}(t)| $ is bounded by a finite sum, then the sequence $\{x_n(t)\}$ uniformly converges? (This sounds wrong and I'm pretty sure it is?)

$\bf{More\ details\ on\ what\ my\ lecturer\ has\ written:}$

So the Theorem considers the first order ODE $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t,x)\ , \ x(t_0)=x_0 $$
where f(t,x) is continuous in the region $ |t-t_0| \leq a \ , \ |x-x_0|\leq b $ , and $f(t,x) $ satisfies the Lipschitz condition for the second argument.

So the proof mainly uses Picard's iteration and the Lipschitz condition w.r.t $x$

(I will leave out some details - my question is regarding DCT not the proof itself)

Using picards iteration on  $ x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,x(s)) ds $, we get $ x_n(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f\left(s,x_{n-1}(s)\right)ds  $

And we need to show that the sequence ${x_n(t)}$ uniformly converges.

Using more Lipschitz condition we have $$ x_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[ x_{k+1}(t) - x_k(t)\right] + x_0(t) $$ and $$ |x_{k+1}(t) - x_{k}(t)| \leq \text{(some finite expression)}$$

Then by dominant convergence theorem, $\{x_n(t)\}$ has uniform convergence.

[[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8N8T.jpg)][[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xutu.jpg)][[part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nvIE.jpg)]

Comment: How can I change the images into a clickable link?

Comment: What do you know about uniform convergence of function sequences? The dominated convergence here is not the one of the Lebesgue theory. I think it can be found under "Weierstraß M-test". (The images are already links, you could remove the ! and the outer link structure to convert them into text links.)

Comment: @LutzLehmann I also have not been taught uniform convergence of sequences (only point-wise) but from what I can understand, a sequence ($f_n$) is uniformly convergent on f if there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ |f_n - f| \leq \epsilon$ (very similar to continuity vs uniform continuity). I read up on the Weierstraß M-test on wikipedia but there isn't any mention of the dominated convergence theory. Is $ |x_{k+1} - x_{k}| $ being bounded by a nonnegative finite sum as shown above equivalent to the M-test? (But the M-test does not take the difference btwn adjacent terms..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform convergence is the norm convergence for the supremum norm. The basic fact about this convergence is that a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions converges to a continuous function, making the space of continuous functions with this norm a complete normed or Banach space.

The usual proofs of Picard-Lindelöf find either that $\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|_{[t_0-h,t_0+h]}\le C(Lh)^k$ or $\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|_{[t_0-h,t_0+h]}\le C\frac{(Lh)^k}{k!}$ so that the series of the upper bounds converges either as geometric or exponential series.

In general, if $\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|_I\le a_k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k<\infty$, then pointwise convergence follows directly and from there for the pointwise limit $x_*$, with some detours,
$$
\|x_n-x_*\|_I\le \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0,
$$
giving the definition of uniform convergence.